# Extrema of function with two variables

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given the function $f(x, y) = 3x^2y − y^3 − 6x$

1. Find the local extrema of $f(x, y)$.

Firstly I find the partial derivitives, namely:
$fx'=6xy-6, fxx''=6y$

$fy'=3x^2-3y^2, fyy''=-6y$

$fxy'=6x,fxy''=0=fyx''$, thus \begin{matrix}
6y& 0 \\
0 & -6y 
\end{matrix}
So $\Delta_2(x,y)=-36y^2<0$ and there are no local extrema.

2)Find the smallest and largest values of $f(x, y)$ in the set
$M = [{(x, y) : x ≥ 0, y ≥ 0, x + y ≤ 1}]$
and find the points in which those values are achieved.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bwTv.png)

But how am I even supposed to find extrema in $[o,1]$ since in the graph there are no points?

Comment: I guess you meant to type `f_x'`$f_x'$ instead of `fx'`$fx'$. Also note `f_{xx}''`$f_{xx}''$. But I don't know what is the meaning of $fxy'$ then. One $'$ means one derivative; $xy$ means two? What you computed is $f''_{xy}$, but then you differentiated again

Answer (score 1):

Extreme values in a closed, bounded regions will either be at a local extrema or on the boundary.   So you need to check the values of the function along the boundary of the region.   You do this by reducing it to a one variable equation on the boundary.

For instance, you have $x=0, y\in [0,1]$ is one boundary, so plugging in $x=0$ has you finding the extreme values of $-y^3$ in $[0,1]$.  Again, the same rule applies,  extreme values will occur at a local extrema or at an endpoint, so you'll check at $y=0,y=1$ and anywhere the derivative is 0.

Your other boundaries are $y=0,  x\in [0,1]$,   and $x+y=1$.  We can solve for either x or y to reduce it to a one variable equation.  For instance, you could plug in $y=1-x$,  reduce it to an equation in $x$ with again boundary values of $[0,1]$